# Probability sum on a biased coin.

Tags: probability

**Q.** If a biased coin with **P(getting a 'Head')=1/3** is to be tossed till a head appears for the first time, then find **P(more than 3 tosses are required to get a 'Head' for the first time)**.

**My approach:** This sum seems like a **binomial probability sum**, but i'm totally stuck, & cannot format the sum binomially.

If i format it binomially **p=1/3**, **(1-p)=2/3**, **n=no of tosses**, but when i'm trying to fix **'x'** i'm stuck, as i can take **'x'=no of heads**, but how can no of heads determine that the 'Head' came at the first time(during tossing)?

Please Help

**Thank you**

Comment: Hint: The probability more than $3$ tosses are required is the probability the first $3$ tosses are tails.

Comment: All you want is the probability of throwing TTT on the first three rows.  No binomial symbols involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to see it the other way around.
This probability is the opposite to have the three first tosses being tails.